# List with a weird shape

Tags: arrays, list, model

I am running the following autoencoder model:

```
    array = np.array([1, 12, 24, 25, 36, 48])
    n_in = len(array)
    seq_in= np.reshape(array, (1, n_in, 1))
    seq_out = seq_in[:, 1:, :]
    n_out = n_in - 1
    visible = tf.keras.Input(shape=(n_in,1))
    encoder = LSTM(257, activation='relu')(visible)
    decoder1 = RepeatVector(n_in)(encoder)
    decoder1 = LSTM(257, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(decoder1)
    decoder1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(decoder1)
    decoder2 = RepeatVector(n_out)(encoder)
    decoder2 = LSTM(257, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(decoder2)
    decoder2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(decoder2)
    model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=[decoder1, decoder2])
    model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='mse')
    model.fit(seq_in, [seq_in,seq_out], epochs=300, verbose=0)
```

Everything works smoothly but when I run y_pred it returns a list with a weird shape that is not convertible into an array because of its inconsistent shape.
How can I obtain a y_pred that is then feedable into another model?

I tried converting it into an array, it returned an error. I tried transposing it, it returned the same error: 'setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (2, 6135618) + inhomogeneous part'.